# Understanding probability of independent events

Tags: probability

I am trying to learn probability, and having a hard time to be honest. What I try to do is to break a problem in terms of event space. For eg, event space for rolling a die is {1,2,3,4,5,6}. For rolling two dice it would be 36 elements with pairs from 1,1 to 6,6. Then I try to calculate probability of a given event using simple basic formula of occurrences/total events.

On topic of probability of independent events, suppose I roll 2 dice and want to calculate probability of 2 on first die and 5 on second die. Book I am reading uses "And" rule for independent events:

```
P(2 and 5) = P(2) * P(5)
```

I am not sure of this approach. When we say event "2 in first roll, 5 in second roll", we basically are talking of an event "2 rolls of die". And so our event space consists of 36 elements, each representing a pair as discussed above. But in above formula, we are multiplying probabilities of events which come from  a different event space(containing 6 elements). So basically we are trying to solve problem belonging to some event space using probabilities from different event space.

Am I wrong in my thinking here?

Comment: $P(2\text{ and }5)=P(2)\times P(5)$ must be looked at as an abbreviation of: $$P(\{(i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\mid i=2,j=5\})=$$$$P(\{(i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\mid i=2\})\times P(\{(i,j)\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2\mid j=5\})$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essential is that probability spaces are **chosen**. This in order to model real-life situations in a natural and convenient way.

If we want to apply probability theory on the throw of a single die then it is quite natural and convenient to go for sample space $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. In that case the real event that the die shows a $5$ corresponds with the theoretical event $\{5\}\subseteq\Omega$.

**But do not think we are stick to that choice.**

If we are interested in a model for the rolling of two dice then it is (again) natural and convenient to go for sample space $\Omega=\{(i,j)\mid i,j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$ and this with $P(\{(i,j)\})=\frac1{36}$ for every singleton event.

In that case the real event that the first die shows a $5$ does corresponds  with the theoretical event $\{(5,j)\mid j\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}=\{(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5),(5,6)\}\subseteq\Omega$.

**Realize that we could have chosen this space also to manage the first situation.**

Only there is no reason to do that, and it is handsome to keep the sample space as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the simple way is to draw the sample space, that is the following

[image]

and immediately you have a clear sight of the elements you need to calculate your probability.

---

**Example 1**: sum of the two dice $\leq 7$ and first die =1

Result: [$\frac{6}{36}$]

---

**Example 2**: first die 2 and second die 5, as you requested: result $\frac{1}{36}$

---

**Example 3**: sum of the two dice $\leq 7$ and at least one "1": Result $\frac{11}{36}$

---

and so on...any question you have to answer you have only to "visualize" and count the favourable events in the above table and divide it by $36$

PS: the plural of "die" is "dice", I amended you post

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean but I'll try to explain what's going on here.

In the first roll, the probability(2) = 1/6 (assuming a fair die). In the second roll, the probability of getting any number stays the same 1/6. The two rolls are independent - they don't affect each other's outcome.
So we get this:
P(R1 = 2, R2 = Y) = 1/6 Y -> {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Thus, we know that if the second roll is taken in fair circumstances, you are going to have to square the previous probability (1/6)², knowing that the sum of all the possible outcomes in the second roll & P(R1 = 2) is equal to P(R1 = 2)

p.s
If someone is willing to format my formulas using latex you're welcome.
I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, your understanding is correct -- and your confusion is understandable. Let me explain.

If we let $X$ denote the value of the first die, and we let $Y$denote the value of the second die, then we may study $(X,Y)$, which exactly takes values in $\{(1,1), (1,2),\ldots,(6,5),(6,6)\}$.

Independence tells us that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X = x, Y = y) = \mathbb{P}(X = x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y).
$$
Indeed the right hand side involves events from different event spaces, namely the marginal event spaces of $X$ and $Y$. In this case, both are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

This shows us that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we only need to know how they act on their individual event space, i.e. we need only to assign a probability to each event $(X=x)$ and $(Y=y)$.

Of course, we may relate an event such as $(X=x)$ to the simultaneous event space. Clearly, $(X=x) = (X=x, Y \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\})$. In particular,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \sum_{y=1}^6 \mathbb{P}(X=x, Y = y).
\end{align*}
(This holds even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.)

I hope this somewhat answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your reasoning is correct, you just need to push it a little further.

- If you roll a die the sample space is $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$
- If you roll two dice the sample space is $\Omega = \{(i,j)\ |\  i,j\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$

What follows is to propose that there is a relationship between both sample spaces. The second is an extension of the first. There is a rule for the creation of this new space at the same time that there is a rule for assigning the probability of each new element.

I think it is possible to interpret that what we do when multiplying probabilities of events from a different sample space is to apply this rule. In this case, since these are independent events, we use the multiplication rule.

You can read a better explanation in [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) by Terence Tao.

PD: Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong!